# Why is infix operator in swift not working?

Tags: swift

My infix operator for powering isn't working. It adds or subtracts.

```
precedencegroup SquareSumOperatorPrecedence {
    lowerThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
    higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
    associativity: left
    assignment: false
}

infix operator ^: SquareSumOperatorPrecedence
func ^(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(lhs, rhs)
}

9 ^ 2// equals 81
// It gives me 11
```

I thought 9 ^ 2 would give me 81, but it gave me 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is already defined as “bitwise XOR” operator for integer operands, and that is what `9 ^ 2` computes:

```
9 ^ 2 = 0b1001 ^ 0b0010 = 0b1011 = 11
```

(See [Advanced Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html) for more information about bitwise operators.)

You defined an operator for *double* operands, and that works as expected if you actually call it with `Double` values:

```
print(9.0 ^ 2.0) // 81
```